# Cyberpunk Web Series

Tags: story-identification, cyberpunk

I'm looking for a cyberpunk video webseries that I believe was made around the late 1990s. It had a woman hacker fighting against a totalitarian government. She had a video camera that helped hide her identity that was almost sentient. She recruited a couple other hackers named Troubleshooter and Tempest to help her. There was another hacker named Lowlux that worked for the government, but was really a double agent.

Comment: What media is this in? Novel, webisode, webcomic, animation?

Comment: @Joe L. Video webseries